# Cats-Effect: How to read a CSV file an process each record

Tags: scala, mapreduce, scala-cats, zio, cats-effect

I am learning cats-effect and as a beginner's project I am trying to read a CSV file and process the data in parallel using Fibers. I normally use Spark for that type of job and I know about FS2.
I am trying to figure out how to "reinvent the wheel" and implement the typical map reduce pattern in cats-effect. This is a learning exercise for me. I am looking for the most "boilerplate solution" to build on. I couldn't find anything online that was understandable to me.

On Multiple Threats I want to

1. Read a file line by line as a String
2. Split the string into an Array by the CSV separator
3. Cast the Array[String] into a case class RowType to obtain Iterable[RowType]
4. Map each row to some value (for example a row of Celsius to a row of Fahrenheit)
5. Reduce the rows to an aggregate result for example: using groupBy and then average. This is a big plus if I can run a reduce job in cats-effect without FS2. I couldn't find any information wrt to that. I guess not a lot of data scientist venture out to Scala and on top away from Spark - I don't mind implementing my own map reduce with steps 1 thru 4.

I hope someone can help out.

Also does anyone have experience with ZIO? Is ZIO better for the type of use cases I have (I am a data scientist)

Thank you!

I have used Resources and the Bracket Pattern. I was able to print out each line in parallel using Fibers to the console returning Unit. I am getting stuck with passing around and manipulating IO[data] instead of passing around IO[Unit].

Comment: The question is a bit too long, it may help if you can show what you already have or split the question in smaller ones. - Anyways, I really really recommend using **fs2** for this, otherwise you would need to fit the whole file in memory or do a lot of work. - Anyways, on top of my head use `scala.io.Source` + `Resource` to get a `Resource[IO, List[String]]` then `use` that and do a `parFoldMapA` where the function inside does the `split` + mapping logic

Comment: Also, check things like **fs2-data** or **breeze**- Anyways remember **cats-effect** and **ZIO** are concurrent fameworks, not parallel data processing frameworks. They excel when your bottleneck is the `I/O` not the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch for you:

```
    def records(source: ZStream[Blocking, Throwable, Byte]): ZStream[Blocking, Throwable, RowType] = {
         source  //stream of bytes from the csv file
        .transduce(ZTransducer.utf8Decode) // decoded to utf-8
        .transduce(ZTransducer.splitLines) // split by \n
        .drop(1) // drop csv header
        .map { line =>
          val terms = line.split(',') // split terms by delimiter
          if (terms.length == numberOfFieldsInWellFormedLine) { // check if there's enough terms
            val field1 = toCelsius(terms(0).toDouble) // transform terms
            val field2 = terms(1)
            Some(RowType(field1, field2)) // create a row class instance from fields
          } else {
            None // drop bad lines
          }
        }
        .collectSome // collect only good lines
    }
    val processedData = records(ZStream.fromFile(pathToCSVFile))
      .mapMParUnordered(100)(processRow(_)) // process in parallel without order
      .groupByKey[Double](row: ProcessedRowType => row.temperature > 100) // group by some criteria
      .collectAll // collect all the results
```

See ZIO docs, it's pretty good. If docs don't help see the source code.